# How to add Jar dependencies for JRuby + Trinidad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, trinidad-gem

I am using JRuby with Trinidad.

It seems I am able to get Trinidad to recognize my class, which is "com.x.HttpClient".

But it doesn't recognize the JARs this class depends on (the HttpClient ones)

I get the error:
**cannot link Java class com.x.HttpClient, probable missing dependency: org/apache/http/params/HttpParams**

I have my jars in my lib/java folder, and my .class file in lib/classes. 
This is my code:

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/java/commons-codec-1.6.jar'
require 'lib/java/httpcore-4.2.4.jar'
require 'lib/java/httpclient-4.2.5.jar'
require 'lib/java/httpmime-4.2.5.jar'
require 'lib/java/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar'
require 'lib/java/fluent-hc-4.2.5.jar'

java_import 'com.x.HttpClient'

class CrawlerController < ActionController::Base

   ...

end
```

Comment: I did temporarily solved it by just unjarring the damn thing, and including the classes. Problem solved for now ^_^ but documentation for JRuby sux, I guess that's to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

[trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad)  has a flag for including jar files

```
--java_lib LIB_DIR            =>  contains .jar files used by the app
```